# How do you recreate sigma notation using Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to plot the following function using Python, numpy and matplotlib:

[image: See function in image:]

for the values of N = 5, 20 and 60.

I've created a list of odd numbers using:

```
def odd(n):
nums = []
for i in range(1, 2*n, 2):
    nums.append(i)
return nums
```

But I don't know how to use this in a sigma function because I need to vary my x values and sum over the function for the range of odd(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is without loops and should work for any value of x and N.

x must be an array or list with more than 1 element

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import matlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def psi(x,N):
   n=np.arange(0,N,2)+1 
   sigma = matlib.repmat((-1)**((n-1)/2),len(x),1).T*np.sin(matlib.repmat(n,len(x),1).T*x)
   PSI = (2/(N+1))*np.sum(sigma,axis=0)
   return PSI
x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)
N=5
y = psi(x,N)
plt.plot(y)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice approach! Be wary that for very large `N`, the term `sigma` will take up a lot of RAM, since it computes and stores every sine wave in the summation.

Comment: I think I can come up with some linear algebra approach to save the ram and calculation time, but it require some thinking :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **plot** (i.e. visualise) the function for some N, then the procedure is as follows:

1. Generate an array of x values. In this case, ranging from -pi to pi makes most sense.
2. Write a loop that computes one sin() at a time, and sum the result in a different array, which we call Psi.
3. Finally multiply the Psi by the constant 2/(N+1).
4. Plot the result

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x is 100 equally spaced points from -pi to pi, inclusive
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100) 
Psi = 0*x # now Psi is an array of zeros

N = 60
# second input of range is N+1 since our index n satisfies 1 <= n < N+1
# third input makes n increment by 2 each loop instead of the default 1
for n in range(1, N+1, 2):
    Psi += -1**((n-1)/2) * np.sin(n*x)

Psi *= 2/(N+1)

plt.plot(x, Psi)
```

[image: N=5]
[image: N=20]
[image: N=60]

Answer (score 2):

Code without pure Python loops:

```
def Psi(x, N=7):
    """Note: N should be odd """
    _s = np.arange(1, int((N + 1) / 2) + 1) 
    return 2 * np.sum(np.where(_s % 2, 1, -1) * np.sin((2 * _s - 1) * x)) / (N + 1)
```